# show js alert on certain conditions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to know how I can display an javascript alert in the following 3 conditions:

1. the reload button from the browser is clicked
2. Reloading the page with a keybort shortcut (e.g. CMD + R)
3. Leaving the actual page by clicking on links on the page.

The user should be able to cancel the reload in the alert window.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/beforeunload

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try [onbeforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/beforeunload) which opens a prompt box for the user

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    return "noooooo... dont go";
}
```

the return value will be displayed as the prompt text, if the user clicks the confirm button, the window continues with the navigation - and stops the navigation if the user chooses cancel

[example in action](http://jsfiddle.net/jaakkytt/yUxuT/)

Comment: Do you want to return that? Or `alert('No don't go');` and then `return false;`. Oops you just edited.

Comment: thanks to your question and pointing out the need for clarification :D